# gd resource not valid when running PHP fetch macro in standalone PHP extension

Tags: php, resources, gd, fetch, php-extension

I created a standalone PHP extension using the ext_skel tool in the PHP extension directory of the PHP source.  I wrote the necessary PHP_FUNCTION's to take in primitive parameters and they work fine.

Now I am writing a function which uses a gd resource parameter and this is where I come into an issue.  When I run a php test code calling this said function, my error log says that Image is not a valid resource and then skips the rest of the function run.

Does anyone know why PHP says that this is not a valid resource?  Do I need to compile my extension differently so that I am able to fetch this resource like in the gd source of say the function imagecolorat?  Below is an example code similar to what was done in imagecolorat function in the gd sourcce.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(myfunction)
{
   zval *IM;
   gdImagePtr im;

   if ( zend_parse_parameter(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "r", &IM) == FAILURE ) return;
   ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(im, gdImagePtr, &IM, -1, "Image", le_gd);

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use one extension's resource type in another extension there are a couple of things you need to do in your code.

1. you need make sure your extension depends on the gd extension (so gd is loaded first)
2. you need to either include gd's extension headers or inline what you need in your code to define C types properly
3. you need to either link against gd or dynamically load phpi_get_le_gd and any other calls you need to make

Here is an example in php-gtk that uses gdImagePtr and the gd extension's resource calls - this uses the dynamic loading route which avoids a hard dependency on the gd extension, but it means that when the gd extension isn't loaded the function will error (not crash, just error).

Note it uses phpi_get_le_gd() which loads le_gd (this is defined and held in the gd extension) for the last  part of ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE and include the headers inline so gd is not necessarily required at the time of compilation (note this can possibly make this code brittle, however, if gd changes things internally)

https://github.com/php/php-gtk-src/blob/def8bf69e3994aa805e8b7fbf894ad399fb41d23/ext/gtk%2B/gdk.overrides#L2038

Your other option is to avoid using the gd extension's resource hooks, and simply use libgd itself.  This would require writing your own resource manipulation or even an object oriented interface and link against libgd itself.

A good example of this is the pecl gdchart extension - which is still in svn here http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/gdchart/ - there are some good examples there are of how to create a PHP extension that uses libgd with information stored inside an object.